# Scala Map pattern matching issue

Tags: scala, dictionary, design-patterns, match

I am new to Scala,

For every key in a map, I want to match a new value

```
class SomeLongNameObject {
    val m: Map[String, String] = Map("a" -> "aa",
      "b" -> "bb",
      "other" -> "someString")

    m.map {
      case (aKey, v) => println("a found")
      case (bKey, v) => println("b found")
      case (k,v) => println("fallback")
    }
  }

  object SomeLongNameObject {
    val aKey = "a"
    val bKey = "b"
  }
  val someObject = new SomeLongNameObject
```

I expect (and desire) that the given map will print

```
a found

b found

fallback
```

however, the result is

```
a found

a found

a found
```

As I understand the `aKey` from the SomeLongNameObject object not used in the `case (aKey, v)`,
Is there a way to force it to use the vals from the object SomeLongNameObject in a more elegant way than below?

```
m.map {
      case (SomeLongNameObject.aKey, v) => println("a found")
      case (SomeLongNameObject.bKey, v) => println("b found")
      case (k,v) => println("fallback")
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `case (aKey, v) => ...` that means "deconstruct the tuple, and assign the first element to a local variable `aKey`, and the second element to local variable `b`. It does not matter whether variables with the same name are already in scope (which in your case they actually aren't, you need to `import SomeLongNameObject._` to bring them in)

One way to tell the compiler you are actually talking about matching to the value of a variable not just assignment is using backticks:

```
    case (`aKey`, v) => ???
```

would work if `aKey` was in scope.

Another way, is to exploit a "secret feature": if a variable name starts with a capital letter, you don't need backticks :) If instead of `aKey`, you had just `A`, this would work: `case (A, v) => ???`

Yet another way is using a guard condition:

```
   case (k,v) if k == aKey => ???
```

Finally, the solution you found yourself: `case (SomeLongNameObject.aKey, v) =>`  is actually quite fine. I personally would rather stick with this approach, just change the name of the object to something meaningful but short (which I would probably do either way – I hate long names with passion), or at least, use an alias:

```
   val keys = SomeLongNameObject
   foo foreach { 
      case (keys.aKey, _) => ???
      ...
```